# Is there a way to have postgresql transactions be commited in the order they were started?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, concurrency

For some business reason I am running the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE updated_at > $1 AND user_id = $2;`.

Consider two transactions, A and B, that are updating rows in table: `UPDATE table SET value = $1, updated_at = NOW() WHERE id = $2;`. Transaction A begins first, so `updated_at` for A's row is sooner than B's row `updated_at`. However, for some reason A is slowed down and B commits first.

If the first query runs before A commits, the software would display B's row but not A's row, which business says is not acceptable.

This could be solved by using `pg_xact_commit_timestamp()` but this returns when the transaction was completed, not commited (it's probably fine for my use case).

Another solution could be to have transactions run `SELECT FROM table WHERE user_id = $1 FOR UPDATE;` before updating the row, but these queries are part of bigger transactions and I think this would destroy the write performance.

A simple solution seems to have transaction B wait for A to commit. Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Comment: @JamesLupolt Thanks you, but it would appear that [the isolation level does not influence the order of execution. It merely detects serialization anomalies to raise an error when they happen.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/239134/267154)

Comment: What to do mean under "transaction" there? If both `A` and `B` are trying to update the same row and `A` acquired exclusive lock via update first, `B` have no chance to update that row until `A` keeps that lock - it needs to wait the completion of `A`.

Comment: Locking is the keyword for what you're trying to do here. Isolation Levels influence how locking is applied, so James is *somewhat* right. But as Andrey points out, because you have 2 write queries, proper locking should already be applied (since writes block writes), regardless of which isolation level you're using (typically). So something doesn't make sense in your description.

Comment: @J.D. `NOW()` [returns the time at the beginning of the transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT). In the situation explained here, A starts before B, so B's updated_at is indeed later, This is the root of the problem.

Comment: @J.D. Regarding locking, this is exactly the solution that I envisioned: `SELECT FROM table WHERE user_id = $1 FOR UPDATE;` which would lock all row for the given user_id, preventing B from doing it's update until A is commited or aborted, but this will degrade performance as B could be updating other tables in the meantime.

Comment: @DontBreakAlex Sorry I skimmed your code and missed the `NOW()`. That makes more sense. Re-regarding locking, you should be experiencing it already. I don't quite understand your problem still. You've only provided a single `UPDATE` statement which should be atomic - meaning the `updated_at` column can only successfully be set when the statement actually successfully executes. So if A truly starts first, it'll lock the table and set the `updated_at` correctly while B waits on it to release that lock. It's not possible for the `UPDATE` statement for A to start and then B's `UPDATE` statement...

Comment: ...to start after, and acquire a lock and commit it's changes while A's was already running. Of course other statements within the transactions that come before the `UPDATE` statement can run at different times before and after each other, between A and B, but none of that should matter since you don't set the `updated_at` column until the `UPDATE` statement you've provided us. Which again runs atomically, and can't start, lock the table, and then a separate `UPDATE` statement to same row starts after but commits before the original `UPDATE` releases the lock (commits or rolls back) first.

Comment: @J.D. I think UPDATE statements only lock rows, not the whole table, and in the described situation, two separate rows are updated

Comment: @DontBreakAlex you should probably mention that in your Post, as most people will assume you're talking about the same row / id, especially when you only have one query example with `WHERE id = $2`, in reference to both examples. In that case, you're not really talking about concurrency, but I understand what you're asking now. In some database systems, sometimes an `UPDATE` statement will escalate the lock form row to table level but obviously you're not currently seeing that occur. In your case you'd want to exclusively lock the table then yourself or better more granularly on the other row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have bigger transactions, using `now()` or `current_timestamp` is questionable, because these functions return the *transaction timestamp*, taken at the start of the database transaction. `clock_timestamp()`, which returns the current time, would be better. Still, a transaction that committed first could end up with a later timestamp.

I agree that locks would be a bad solution: they are bad for performance and can even cause deadlocks.

I question the requirement. Why does it matter when the database transaction committed?

I guess that "business" does not really care when the transactions committed, they want a reliable ordering of the transactions. Transactions don't have a well-defined order in PostgreSQL. All you need is a logical ordering. I would say that if the statement you show is the last statement in the transaction, and if you use `clock_timestamp()`, the solution is good. Your timestamp defines the order of transactions. The actual commit time (which will be shortly after) is irrelevant.

Comment: Business is worried that rows could be displayed in a illogical order: if I consider events in order A, B, C and updated so they are ordered C, B, A, then the query should never return events in the order B, C, A, because B was updated before A. The valid sequences are A-B-C,  A-C-B or C-B-A.

Comment: This never occurred in practice, but I would like to by able to say to business that this cannot happen. A solution would be to set updated_at to the time the transaction committed, but I don't think this is possible in postgresql. Can you think of any other solution than locking the latest row of the user with `SELECT FROM table WHERE user_id = $1 ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;` ?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to ensure that the timestamp reflects the commit order, unless you serialize transactions. It would be sad to do that to solve a problem that does not really exist. Tell "business" that your timestamp reflects the order of the transactions exactly. If they are smart enough to know that "the order of transactions" is somewhat arbitrary, they should also be smart enough to understand that it does not matter.

Comment: A bit of context: they care about that because this query is ran on a mobile phone in someone's car, so it won't run very often because of data caps and bad reception. Business doesn't want someone to believe that they should drive from C to A only for C -> B -> A to appear while they are driving (B should always appear before A). I just I'll just ignore events if they are not at least 1 second old, thanks for your help (I don't have enough reputation to accept the answer)

Comment: So your real problem is that you select everything where the timestamp is more recent than the last time you selected, and then rely that no row with an older timestamp than the most recent one you got will appear in the future. Yes, leaving a grace period of a second is a good idea. I think everybody can accept an answer, perhaps you just need to wait a little.

Comment: @DontBreakAlex Again, the only way to guarantee transactional order consistency, from the database layer is via locking. The only other alternatives is to change the business process or write the application code in a way that ensures transactional consistency, but that's typically difficult and not something we'd be able to comment on without knowing your codebase. Locking is designed exactly for guaranteed order of events consistency. I agree with Laurenz that serializable locking would not be great, especially if you do it at the transaction isolation level or table level. Your best bet...

Comment: ...is at the row level, if it were possible. Idk PostgreSQL enough to say so though.

Comment: Everything will be synced at some point, it would just be bad user experience to have stuff appear in the middle of an existing sequence